# mahlo and hyper-inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

Wikipedia states that a Mahlo cardinal is hyper-inaccessible, hyper-hyper-inaccessible, etc. Is this a characterisation of Mahlo? If not what about "alpha = hyper^alpha-inaccessible" with the obvious transfinite recursive definition of hyper^alpha-inaccessible ?

Comment: I added the large-cardinals and set-theory tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No amount of hyperinaccessibility or hyperhyperinaccessibility and so on can be provably equivalent to Mahloness (unless those notions are inconsistent). The reason is that if $\kappa$ is Mahlo, then all its hyperinaccessibility and hyperhyperinacessibility  properties and so on are expressible in the structure $\langle V_\kappa,\in\rangle$, once one knows that $\kappa$ is regular, since they have to do only with what is happening eventually below $\kappa$. But when $\kappa$ is Mahlo, then there are many inaccessible $\delta$ with $V_\delta\prec V_\kappa$, since the set of $\alpha$ with $V_\alpha\prec V_\kappa$ is club in $\kappa$ by a Lowenheim-Skolem argument. Any such $\delta$ will therefore have exactly the same hyperhyperinacessibility properties as $\kappa$, even though when $\kappa$ is the least Mahlo, then no such $\delta$ is Mahlo. So those properties do not imply Mahloness.

Note that the property of $\kappa$ being Mahlo is naturally expressed in $V_{\kappa+1}$, since it makes reference to stationarity, which requires one to consider all subsets of $\kappa$.

Comment: That's a very good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

$\kappa$ is Mahlo is it has stationary many inaccessibles below it, or alternatively every normal (continuous in terms of limit ordinals) function has a fixed point within $\kappa$.

This is the same because one can define a CLUB set as an image of a normal function, so having stationary many inaccessibles below $\kappa$ means there's always a fixed point.

In this way, a Mahlo cardinal is indeed inaccessible, as well as hyper-inaccessible and so on.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahlo_cardinal) says "every normal function has a **regular** fixed point in $\kappa$". Is it equivalent to the definition you gave?

Comment: I have encountered yet another definition: "An inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ is Mahlo iff every normal function $\kappa\to\kappa$ has an inaccessible cardinal in its range". Is it equivalent to the one you gave?